# How do I extract a row of a file in python?

Tags: python, csv, raspberry-pi

I have an rfid reader hooked up to a raspberry pi.  When i scan a card, I get a UID number stored in my python file as "backData"  I would like to store all of my users in a separate file (IE: csv or txt file), instead of at the top of my code and then read that file to authenticate and extract the relevant row.  My current python code is as follows:

```
user1 = [1,23,45,678,987]
user2 = [9,87,65,432,123]

if  backData == user1:
  f = open("/mnt/lock_logs/lock_log.csv", "a");
  print f
  value = ('\n' 'user1,FOB,') + (',') + time.strftime("%c")
  myString = str(value)
  f.write(myString)
  f.close()
  GPIO.digitalWrite(RELAY, GPIO.HIGH)
  GPIO.digitalWrite(LEDBLUE, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.digitalWrite(LEDGREEN, GPIO.HIGH)
  print "Access Granted"
  time.sleep(1)
  GPIO.digitalWrite(RELAY, GPIO.LOW)
  time.sleep(3)
  GPIO.digitalWrite(LEDGREEN, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.digitalWrite(LEDBLUE, GPIO.HIGH)
```

So Ideally, I would read a csv file, find the UID, and print the row to a log.  The csv file would look like this.

```
[1,23,456,78,987], Full Name
```

Thanks in advance for reviewing my issue.

Comment: read the line, use split() and an index

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below will read the file into a dict in the script.

```
import csv

users = {}
with open('users.csv', 'r') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    for row in reader:
       id = row[0][1:-1].split(',')
       name = row[1]
       users[id] = name
```

That will build you a dict of ids to names.  But honestly why not just use json and dump()/load() the file as a whole?  Is it being used by some other program or service?  Your main difficulty is translational of a text representation to a data representation, that what formats like json do, why not use them?

if it was json format it would be:

```
import json

users = {}
with open('users.json', 'r') as fp:
   users = json.load(fp)
```

And it would be much less error prone than the assumption I made in the first version. The resulting `users` would look like this once loaded:

```
{
    [1,23,45,678,987]: 'name1', 
    [9,87,65,432,123]: 'name2'
}
```

So to get the user would be:

```
if users.get(backData, None) in ('name1', 'name2'):
    #stuff
```

of

```
if users.get(backData, None) is not None:
    #stuff
```

json is just a serialization format.  So whatever data structure you call dump() on is what you'll get back when you call load().  Check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Comment: I like this suggestion but have no experience with json.  So if I utilize your json code above, would my python code after that then say "if backData == users"  #Open door. Also, how would I extract the row with that UID once multiple users are added to the json file?  Thanks for your time

Comment: Added details about what ``users`` would end up looking like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used to accomplish this..

```
uid_dict = dict()
uid_file = "/mnt/lock_logs/users.txt"
log_file = "/mnt/lock_logs/lock_log.csv"
fieldnames = ['UUID', 'USERS']

# UID DICTIONARY
with open(uid_file, "r") as f:
  reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=",")
  for row in reader:
    uid_dict[row['USERS'].strip()] = [int(i) for i in row['UUID'].split()]

  for key, value in uid_dict.iteritems():
    if backData == value:
      with open(log_file, "a") as f:
        f.write(key + "\n")        
      GPIO.output(RELAY, GPIO.HIGH)
      time.sleep(1)
      GPIO.output(RELAY, GPIO.LOW)
      break
```